# Java: Optimize/Increase run speed in a DFS

Tags: java, arraylist, depth-first-search

So I've been working on a problem, and the basic premise is that given a grid of any size, I need to calculate the number of "tours". A tour being a run that starts at the top left point (which I use the point x=1, y=1 for) and ends at the bottom left point (x=1 y=max, whatever the max for 'y' is). In addition to this, it has to touch every other point along the way, and can only visit any point in the grid once.

The way I have it written below, it runs in ~42-45 seconds, but I'd like to get it to run in 30 seconds or less, if possible. So, my question to you, what can I change or take out that will make it run faster?

I've tried making everything not static and instantiating the class (which added a few seconds to my run time).

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Date;

public class CodingPuzzle
{
public static List<Point> lAllPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
public static int iMaxX;
public static int iMaxY;
public static int iCompletePaths = 0;

public static void depthFirstSearch(Point current, Stack<Point> result)
{
    if (result.contains(current))
        return;

    result.push(current);

    if (current.x == 1 && current.y == iMaxY && result.size() == iMaxX*iMaxY)
    {
        // This is a complete path
        iCompletePaths++;
    }
    for (Point p: getPossibleMoves(current))
    {
        depthFirstSearch(p, result);
    }

    // No path was found
    result.pop();
    return;
}

public static List<Point> getPossibleMoves (Point fromPoint)
{
    int iCurrentPointIndex = lAllPoints.indexOf(fromPoint);
    List<Point> lPossibleMoves = new ArrayList<Point>();

    if (fromPoint.x == 1 && fromPoint.y == 1)
    {
        // Top left point
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + iMaxY));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.x == 1 && fromPoint.y == iMaxY)
    {
        // Bottom left point. Should always be the last point. No valid moves.
        // If a path gets here before the end it shouldn't need to continue.
    }

    else if (fromPoint.x == iMaxX && fromPoint.y == 1)
    {
        // Top right point
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.x == iMaxX && fromPoint.y == iMaxY)
    {
        // Bottom right point
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - 1));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.x == 1 && fromPoint.y != iMaxY)
    {
        // Any other point on the left side
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + iMaxY));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.x == iMaxX)
    {
        // Any other point on the right side
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.y == 1)
    {
        // Any other point on the top
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + iMaxY));
    }

    else if (fromPoint.y == iMaxY && fromPoint.x != 1)
    {
        // Any other point on the bottom
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + iMaxY));
    }

    else
    {
        // Any other point not on an edge.
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - 1));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex - iMaxY));
        lPossibleMoves.add(lAllPoints.get(iCurrentPointIndex + iMaxY));
    }

    return lPossibleMoves;
}

public static void setUpGrid(int x, int y)
{
    iMaxX = x;
    iMaxY = y;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)
            lAllPoints.add(new Point(i, j));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Date start = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    setUpGrid(10, 4);
    Stack<Point> sCurrentPoints = new Stack<Point>();
    depthFirstSearch(lAllPoints.get(0), sCurrentPoints);
    Date end = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long total = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    System.out.println(iCompletePaths + " paths found in " + total/1000 + " seconds.");
}
```

Comment: unless there is a specific issue you are addressing in the question - it better fits [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you tried performance profiling the code?

Comment: I haven't tried performance profiling, can you recommend something good to use for it? (Something free, perhaps.)

Comment: Also, the easiest and quickest way to profile is running the JVM with the [`-Xprof`](https://www.google.com/search?q=xprof) switch. Then there's the [VisualVM](https://www.google.com/search?q=visualvm) which is included in the JDK. Simple, but those two tools are enough for the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What others say. It will help you to become a better programmer.

Other than that, here's the quick win you're looking for - switch from `Stack` to [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), namely [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html). This single change made it 44 % faster on my `Java 7 -server` machine.

Comment: Wow. That one change got me down to 25 seconds for a full run. I do understand what the others were trying to tell me, and I understand the importance (I already knew where it was spending most of the time. I've taken as much out as possible from that, from what I can see.) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Stack is old (from Java 1.0) and long abandoned. It's there just to maintain the compatibility and it's basically just an adapted [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) - which is a synchronized version of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). ArrayList is utterly bad when you add to (and remove from) the beginning of it, because it always has to reallocate again to shift all the other elements you're not working with (think of it as a resizable array).

Answer (score 3):

I would reduce the amount of work the code is doing to get the count.

```
public class CodingPuzzle2 {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public CodingPuzzle2(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int countPaths(int x, int y) {
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[width][height];
        int[] count = {0};
        countPaths(x, y, visited, 1,  count);
        return count[0];
    }

    private void countPaths(int x, int y, boolean[][] visited, int depth, int[] count) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height || visited[x][y])
            return;
        visited[x][y] = true;
        try {
            if (x == 0 && y == height - 1) {
                if (depth == width * height)
                    count[0]++;
                return;
            }
            countPaths(x, y + 1, visited, depth+1, count);
            countPaths(x + 1, y, visited, depth+1, count);
            countPaths(x - 1, y, visited, depth+1, count);
            countPaths(x, y - 1, visited, depth+1, count);
        } finally {
            visited[x][y] = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        CodingPuzzle2 cp = new CodingPuzzle2(10,4);
        int count = cp.countPaths(0, 0);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("%,d paths found in %.3f seconds.%n", count, time / 1e9);
    }
}
```

prints

```
2,329 paths found in 1.758 seconds.
```

Comment: This. Doing somebody's homework in ten minutes and making it faster by a magnitude. This man deserves the Accept tick, because he utilized what all the other people around were pointing at. Learn from this - please don't copy that and claim it as yours :).

Comment: If it is someones `[homework]`, they still have to be able to explain why they wrote the code the way they did, so it would be a bad idea to submit anything they don't understand.  I couldn't see a simple way to say, change this and that and that until all that is left is the class name. ;)  I usually expect to make code at least 10x faster. ;)

Comment: Absolutely. The only issue I have with this answer (and it is great, there's no doubt about that.) is that it teaches me relatively little, compared to one that tells me a change (like how he went from an ArrayList of points to a 2d array of booleans) and perhaps a small reason why (lots of performance increase, for instance). I commend you for your effort, and I'll definitely take it for a reference, but I won't be using it as my solution.

Comment: Try and see if you use some of the changes I made in your code. For example, you don't need to use Date() if you are just going to call getTime().

Comment: Anyone else get this as an interview question?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is profile your code (as Peter said in the comments on your question). It's hard to 'make things faster' without an idea of where you're spending time. But your algorithm may be somewhat inefficient. For profiling, you can use jvisualvm, which ships with the Oracle JVM.

You might want to look into [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms) to solve for the [Hamiltonian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) of a graph, which is effectively what you're doing. There are more efficient solutions than brute-force.